# Install Pillow for Python 3.4 on Mac Os X Mavericks (10.9)

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library

I want to install Pillow for Python 3.4 (PIL fork) on my mac osx 10.9. I've searched on the net but found no way to install it. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

I have both Python 2 and Python 3 installed via [Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python#python-2x-or-python-3x):

> Homebrew provides a formula for Python 2.7.x and one for Python 3.x. They don't conflict, so they can both be installed. The executable `python` will always point to the 2.x and `python3` to the 3.x version.

So:

```
$ brew update
$ brew install python3
```

This also gives `pip` for Python 2 and `pip3` for Python 3. So you can [install Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#mac-os-x-installation) like:

```
$ brew install libtiff libjpeg webp little-cms2
$ pip3 install pillow
```

Then:

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr  9 2014, 11:51:10) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.38)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> im = Image.open("image.png")
>>> im.show()
```